# Tapestry 5: test response of page

Tags: junit, tapestry

I have a page, that page return `StreamResponse` (json):

```
StreamResponse onActivate() { .... }
```

Server support POST/GET/PUT/DELETE requests with parameters for that page.

I want write a test (junit) for this requests and assert results.

How I can did it?

Comment: What exactly do you want to test? How different HTTP verbs handled by tapestry app? Or just implementation of `onActivate()`?

Comment: Yes, I want to be sure, that my server works properly, that it correct answer on some request. So, what I did now? I'm run server, then call curl to some my server page and control that server my return (server get me some json-data).

Answer (score 0):

For pre-Tapestry 5.4 there's a `SeleniumTestCase` that you can use to run integration tests for your app:
https://tapestry.apache.org/integration-testing.html

Note that Selenium RC that's used in `SeleniumTestCase` has been deprecated and new projects shouldn't use it.

Recent versions of tapestry recommend to use Spock + Geb for integration testing, one example can be found [here](https://github.com/apache/tapestry-5/blob/95a548ec488a3c09c16117a0e6f9d3ce28db0322/tapestry-webresources/src/test/groovy/t5/webresources/tests/WebResourcesSpec.groovy). There's a 3rd party project [tapestry-geb](https://github.com/eddyson-de/tapestry-geb) maintained by a Tapestry committer that can help you setup the Geb for your tests.

You can also start your app using [`PageTester`](https://tapestry.apache.org/unit-testing-pages-or-components.html), but as far as I know `PageTester` itself can't work with custom HTTP verbs, so you'll need to use something else for sending requests, i.e. using the same Spock + Geb.

Note that it's not something common to have a Tapestry page that responds to different HTTP verbs and returns JSON response. It looks like you're trying to implement some sort of REST API, in this case I'd recommend you to look at Tynamo's [tapestry-resteasy](http://www.tynamo.org/tapestry-resteasy+guide/).

With tapestry-resteasy you can expose a Tapestry service as a REST endpoint. In such case you can use above mentioned `PageTester` to test your the endpoint as a regular Tapestry service.